# Connect to VPN xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Hello I am using this code to connect vpn with c# my code can connect and disconnect and create vpn and it working fine but i want use it in xamarin android i do search google but No result

```
 private static string FolderPath => string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
        "\\VPN");

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(FolderPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("[VPN]");
        sb.AppendLine("MEDIA=rastapi");
        sb.AppendLine("Port=VPN2-0");
        sb.AppendLine("Device=WAN Miniport (IKEv2)");
        sb.AppendLine("DEVICE=vpn");
        sb.AppendLine("PhoneNumber=" + txtHost.Text);

        File.WriteAllText(FolderPath + "\\VpnConnection.pbk", sb.ToString());

        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("rasdial \"VPN\" " + txtUsrname.Text + " " + txtPassword.Text + " /phonebook:\"" + FolderPath +
                      "\\VpnConnection.pbk\"");

        File.WriteAllText(FolderPath + "\\VpnConnection.bat", sb.ToString());

        var newProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = FolderPath + "\\VpnConnection.bat",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            }
        };

        newProcess.Start();
        newProcess.WaitForExit();
        btnConnect.Enabled = false;
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(FolderPath + "\\VpnDisconnect.bat", "rasdial /d");

        var newProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = FolderPath + "\\VpnDisconnect.bat",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            }
        };

        newProcess.Start();
        newProcess.WaitForExit();
        btnConnect.Enabled = true;
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;
    }
```

or I want convert it to xamarin android and 
connect or disconnect sorry for my english

Comment: Obviously you can't do this with pbk file as it is Windows specific... Prolly you can do this with android specific API but it is way too broad.

Comment: If you are trying to start an Android-based 3rd-party VPN, consult the app/vendor's documentation. If you are trying to write/embed your own Android VPN, consult the Android docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html

Comment: can you give me any example @Selvin

Comment: Please I need your help @SushiHangover